# Going through all occurences of class on slider change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the colors of a div's text as a slider moves. I got it working so that the first number will change. However, I need this to happen on many div's. I am currently trying to use .each() but I am not getting the results I want. The second div, and the rest of them, just change to whatever color the first div is. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiriek/5mv3snwn/1/) that shows you guys what I have so far. The numbers in the div's should be 'red' if they are greater than the slider value and 'green' if they are less than the slider value. They seem to be changing based on the value of the first div.

```
function updateSliderValue(newValue) {   
    $('#rangeValue1').val(newValue);
    var str = $('#someid').text()
    var num = parseFloat(str, 10);

    $('.value').each(function(){
        if (newValue > num) {
            $('.wrapped .value').removeClass('bully').addClass('normal');
        } else {
            $('.wrapped .value').removeClass('normal').addClass('bully');
        }
    });
}
```

This is the JQuery code that I am using to try to correctly change the div colors.

Thanks so much!
Kirie

Comment: If you are going through multiple elements with .each() you can use $(this) inside the function to refer to the current element. So it should be $(this).removeClass()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $(this) and define num inside $('.value').each();

```
$('.value').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).text();
    var num = parseFloat(str, 10);
    if (newValue >= num) {
        $(this).removeClass('bully').addClass('normal');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('normal').addClass('bully');
    }
});
```

Here's an edited version: http://jsfiddle.net/61vd3u79/

Answer (score 0):

I think if you slightly change your code like this, it should work

```
function updateSliderValue(newValue) {   
  $('#rangeValue1').val(newValue);
  var str = $('#someid').text()
  var num = parseFloat(str, 10);

  $('.value').each(function(){
    if (newValue > num) {
        $(this).removeClass('bully').addClass('normal');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('normal').addClass('bully');
    }
  });
}
```

$(this) references the current div in the foreach.